# How to create and use Protocol , if more then one class implements

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I Want to create A **Protocol** in my project For conform some parameters I have three classes to use so I want the classes  to conform the protocol.

So please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: xcode, perimeters plz ????

Comment: singalimageView,animationimageview,VideoView that 3 perameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just Give Basic Idea for how to Create **Protocol**

[Also Read This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

```
#DetailViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MasterDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
@end


@interface DetailViewController : MasterViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MasterDelegate> customDelegate; 

#DetailViewController.m

if([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getButtonTitile:)])
{
          [self.customDelegate getButtonTitile:button.currentTitle];    
}

#MasterViewController.m

create obj of DetailViewController

DetailViewController *obj = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
obj.customDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reportTypeVC animated:YES];

and add delegate method in MasterViewController.m for get button title.

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Custom Delegate  Method

-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", btnTitle);

}
```

Comment: Suggestion: declare the method optional in the protocol since you are showing an example of testing for the method, which should only be necessary for an optional protocol.

Answer (score 0):

**As you do for one class, use it for three or even dozens of classes, it doesn't matter how many protocols your class conforms to.**

As you can see, i added randomly many delegate protocols here

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, NSCoding, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@end
```

To Create a protocol, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)